# Meteor/Cordova app is not saving graph.facebook images into data cache

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor

I have designed my Meteor/Cordova app to allow offline use for some functionalities.  Images loaded from external sources are being cached while the app is in memory, but once the app is removed from memory or the device is restarted and the data connection is off, the images previously loaded from "https://graph.facebook.com/xxx" are not loaded anymore, but images from other sites such as "https://ucarecdn.com/" are being loaded perfectly.

Any idea why images from graph.facebook.com are not being stored in the app data cache?  The image link remains the same after the device is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this is the reason but all FB(and Instagram) links to images are signed URLs. They work for a while and then they don't. If you want to link a FB image to view it in another website, eventually it will not load because the link expires (the link contains a token). In this case you will request a new token (which means a different link). I see in FB images come with a 14 days cache policy. I do not know what is the case for the Graph but I'd assume you cannot get a photo by just "https://graph.facebook.com/some_image.jpg", you would need a signed link or eventually you will be returned an error saying that you need a token. Do you get an error? Could you provide a full link to an image? If you can load an image, can you check in a Chrome Dev tools / Network, what is the cacheing policy for the image and the full path (in case it redirects you to some other url).
Think of this: I post something in FB and then FB deletes it for any reason or I want to delete it but ... thousand of users can still see it in various mobile apps or other websites because the image is cached. Well, this should not be the case and this is why social networks expire links to resources. I think in FB T&C is also mentioned that you should not cache or store their images.

Comment: I'm just taking the profile picture from FB, I guess the link is permanent, check it:
https://graph.facebook.com/10161387641990065/picture?type=square&amp;height=200&amp;width=200

The number after facebook.com/ is the User ID.

Comment: On your transaction you get: Status Code: 302  (Temporary redirect) and in headers: cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate and it is expired: expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT. So, as I said, you only get access to the image once per 1 call. There is no caching. How I did it: open a new Chrome tab, open Dev tools with Network tab in view, paste your link and hit enter and then look for your FB asset (easiest to find is to look by the 302 status). Options: grab it, store it in S3 with Cloudfront and set your own caching policy on it. Or store it in a mobile DB.

Comment: I see.  I think the answer is that the img object has a property of `no-cache`, and browsers don't keep it cached, despite the expiration date.  Would you mind to edit your answer to accept it.

Comment: I woudn’t mind but you understating your query/problem was more important for me than you accepting my answer. And the explanation goes a bit beyond the cacheing and is more related to the fact that you have a link to a redirect not to a image.

Comment: Thank you Paul.  I suggest to edit the answer to state clearly why the image is not cached.  The current answer suggest some things that are not completely true at least in my case exposed, such as that the links has tokens to be accessible the resource just once.  I have the link saved in my system and I access the image (online) several times.  By the way, the link redirect but returns the image resource.